# Unable to receive events through EsperIOSocketAdapter

Tags: java, esper, complex-event-processing

I'm trying to send Events to the Esper engine through sockets and ran into some problem.

i've configured the EsperIOSocketAdapter properties and when EsperIOSocketAdapter.start() method is invoked , it starts a new daemon thread which will listen for clients , but daemon thread exits as parent thread exits before a socket client actually tries to connect.

my code snippet is as follows:

```
            ConfigurationSocketAdapter adapterConfig = new ConfigurationSocketAdapter();

            SocketConfig socket = new SocketConfig();
            socket.setDataType(DataType.CSV);
            socket.setPort(6789);
            adapterConfig.getSockets().put("CourseSocket", socket);


            EsperIOSocketAdapter socketAdapter = new EsperIOSocketAdapter (adapterConfig, "CourseSocket");
            socketAdapter.start();
```

Another doubt is in programs without using the SocketAdapter i used to send events through the code

EPRuntime.sendEvent(new TestEvent(event));

While using SocketAdapter, shoud i use sendEvent() or events will automatically pushed into the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket problem seems to be of a generic nature where the JVM is terminating because you do not have any non-daemon threads running.  Make the parent thread (or the socket thread) a non-daemon thread and the JVM will not terminate. (Make sure you can actually stop the thread or your JVM will be stubborn about shutting down :)  )

When you use the SocketAdapter, your "sending client" is remote to the physical EPRuntime, but you use the remote socket to send events over the socket, as outlined in the [docs](http://esper.codehaus.org/esperio-4.3.0/doc/reference/en/html/adapter_socket.html).